# how to install the dependencies for a java software in ubuntu.?

Tags: java, ubuntu, dependencies, rpm

Him im trying to install java using RPM and i want to know how to install the missing dependencies for java. Im unable to proceed to the further steps without installing the dependencies.

Comment: Don't use RPM on ubuntu! Do use the [WebUpd8 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java).

Comment: Any specific reason??

Comment: use sudo apt-get install java ;) , I would suggest to download the oracle JDK package zip, unzip the files and then set the classpath.

Comment: @varun Ubuntu is derived from Debian, and they use deb package files (not rpm).

Comment: @BilboBaggins:thanks. il try your suggestions.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: thanks. Il try doing it.:)

Answer (score 0):

From Terminal

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

Also set JAVA_HOME variable to

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

Answer (score 0):

First update and upgrade apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get update -q \
&& sudo apt-get upgrade
```

add jdk 11 to your ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: openjdk-r/ppa
```

Update again and install java:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```